# Obtain tangent from a composite function with unknown $f(x)$ but inc values of $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$

Tags: functions, derivatives

Supposing we have a composite function,

$$\ g(x) = (f(-\cos(x)))^3$$

and we want to find the tangent line at $\ x=\frac{\pi}{6}$

and the only additional information we are given are values for $f(x)$  and $f'(x)$:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} \hline
\ x & \ f(x) & \ f'(x) \\ \hline
\ -\frac{\sqrt 2}{2} & 0 & 2 \\ \hline
\ -\frac{1}{2} & -7 & -9 \\ \hline
\ -\frac{\sqrt 3}{2} & 2 & -\sqrt 5 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

A start is to obtain the derivative of the composite function using the chain rule, i.e.:

$$\ g'(x) = \frac{d}{dx}(f(-\cos(x))^3 = 3 \sin (x)f(-\cos(x))^2 f'(-\cos(x)) $$

but I am stuck at this point, any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the equation of the tangent of a real map at a given point?

Comment: at a given point it is the line y=mx+b .. with m obtained by the derivative and the coordinates being used to obtain the values of x and y via y - y1 = m (x - x1) ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall $\sin (\pi /6)=\frac 1 2$, $\cos (\pi /6)=\frac {\sqrt 3} 2$. When $x=\pi /6$ we get $g(x)=8$. The equation of the tangent line is $y-8=g'(\pi /6) (x-\pi /6)$.

Answer (score 0):

With $ \cos \frac{\pi}{6}= \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3}$ and $ \sin \frac{\pi}{6}=\frac{1}{2}$ you can compute $g(\frac{\pi}{6})$ and $g'(\frac{\pi}{6})$